# How to make sure Firestore cached data is up to date in Android?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am making an Android app where I have TabLayout on top of the layout which is responsible for filtering my list. On first start I try to get data from cache using Source.CACHE, then if no results are found I go  for Source.SERVER. I have made some algorithms to track top and bot cached documents and based on them download additional data from server, regardless the query. This is working fine, but problem occurs if someone else has edited some of those cached documents, my app will load old data, which is fine.
I am using *get()* to get data just once because I don't want new items popping around while user scrolls.

So how would I accomplish that my cached data is up to date with latest data?
I have found some "solutions" where is being said it is impossible without downloading data, but could it be done with setting one time *EventListener* on cached data to retreive updated data and read only changed documents, as it is being done when you want realtime updates?

My current *onCompleteListener*

```
 @Override
public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {

    if(task.isSuccessful())
    {
        boolean isEmpty = task.getResult().isEmpty();
        if(isEmpty && task.getResult().getMetadata().isFromCache()) {
            query.limit(JobModel.LIMIT).get(Source.SERVER).addOnCompleteListener(this);
        }
        else
        {
            for(DocumentSnapshot documentChange : task.getResult().getDocuments()) {
                JobModel jobModel = documentChange.toObject(JobModel.class);
                jobModel.setId(documentChange.getId());
                jobLoading.getJobModels().add(jobModel);
            }

            int querySnapshotSize = task.getResult().size();

            //This saves first and last Cached documents - ONLY if its from Cache and has at least 1 item - SPECIAL CASE - FROM CASE
            if(task.getResult().getMetadata().isFromCache() && querySnapshotSize > 0)
                onLastVisibleJobCallback.setCachedEdgeDocuments(task.getResult().getDocuments().get(0), task.getResult().getDocuments().get(querySnapshotSize-1));

           
            if(querySnapshotSize < JobModel.LIMIT)
                onLastJobReachedCallback.setReached(true);
            else
            {
                DocumentSnapshot lastVisibleProduct = task.getResult().getDocuments().get(querySnapshotSize - 1);
                onLastVisibleJobCallback.setLastVisibleJob(lastVisibleProduct);
            }

            Log.d("LIVE_DATA", "New jobs job LOADED, size: " + jobLoading.getJobModels().size());
            setValue(jobLoading);           
        }
    }
    else
        Log.d("LIVE_DATA", task.getException().getMessage());
}
```

Comment: I think this **[article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-drastically-reduce-the-number-of-reads-when-no-documents-are-changed-in-firestore-8760e2f25e9e)** might help.

Comment: Glad to hear from you, I have actually read that article, but I was not sure how to implement it for pagination. Because, I got StackOverflowError when putting DocumentSnapshot into SharedPreferences via json.. And the second thing bothering me was that I would need to use query for "lastModified" and then I couldnt use query for other fields which I need, eg. "price"..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to control when the cache is updated, you'll need to:

1. Store a value in the data that indicates when it was last updated. I typically call this `lastUpdated`.
2. Keep track of when your app has last loaded the data, stored in something like a SharedPreference called `lastLoaded`.
3. Run a query when you want to update the cache for documents where `lastUpdated >= lastLoaded`, and then update `lastLoaded` to the current time.

This **does** download the updated data, which also means that it is indeed "it is impossible [to update the cache] without downloading data".

Comment: okay, as stated in 3. of your answer, that Query would download only changed documents from lastLoaded but how would I know (if Firestore doesn't handle it on it's own) which documents to update after downloading updates?

Comment: I'm not sure what "to update" means there, but I expect you'd have to process all documents that were downloaded (so process all query results).

Comment: "to update" meant to set new(changed) value..Processing that data I might get proper results in my recyclerview, but what about next time user enters app, wouldn't he still get the old value (before update), because it's value was never changed in Firestore cache? I mean I am a bit confused in which way does Firestore handles that data and cache

Comment: If you get the updated data with a query, it is always updated in the local cache too. The approach I describe is tried and tested, so I recommend giving it a try.

Comment: I think I got it, thank you for your time.